# Formula for twisted generalized quadratic Gauss sums

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, gauss-sums, dirichlet-character

Let $q,a,b$ be integers, $q \geq 1$, $(q,a)=1$, and let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character modulo $q$. Is there a formula for the sum
$$
G_\chi(a,b,q) := \sum_{n(q)} e^{2\pi i \frac{(an^2 + bn)}{q}} \chi(n).
$$
Any ideas on simplification or anything interesting to say of these?

Comment: what is $n(q)$? $0\leqslant n < q$?

Comment: $n \pmod{q}$ (the summand is $q$-periodic). Of course one may choose the range $[0,q)$.

Comment: If $\chi$ is a primitive character, you can expand $\chi$ using additive characters: $$\chi(n) = \frac{1}{\tau(\overline{\chi})} \sum_{h(q)} \overline{\chi}(h)e\left( \frac{nh}{q}\right).$$ If $\chi$ is not primitive, it is induced by some primitive character and a similar analysis holds. Substituting this and interchanging sums, the original sum is $$\frac{1}{\tau(\overline{\chi})} \sum_{h(q)} \overline{\chi}(h) \sum_{n(q)} e\left( \frac{an^2 + (b+h)n}{q}\right).$$ The inner sum is a standard quadratic Gauss sum that can be explicitly evaluated. I'm not sure what this would give in the end.

Comment: The $\tau(\overline{\chi})$ above is the standard Gauss sum attached to the character $\overline{\chi}$ and $e(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$.

Comment: Inserting the formula for Gauss sums here leads to a sum very much like the first. Thus I doubt this will lead somewhere. Considering I have not been able to find a formula online, perhaps there is no simple one?